# Java - How can I change a JScrollBar's buttons dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

I've overridden `BasicScrollBarUI`, but I don't know how to change the buttons after they've been created. How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you overriding `createDecreaseButton` and `createIncreaseButton` methods and create your custom in it then return them? Which things in button do you want to change after creation? UI of button?

Comment: Yeah I am overriding these methods but they create a new button and return it. An option could be to create class variables that point to the returned buttons, and modify them. I just want to change the colors - creating an inverted color theme.

Comment: See [MetalScrollBarUI](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/swing/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalScrollBarUI.java.htm) implementation. The buttons are members of the class and can be updated later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", YourScrollbarUI.class.getName());
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame); 
frame.pack();
```

Take a look at this link for more information of how to update the Look and Feel.
[Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to register your implementation of ScrollBarUI then this should help you:

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", YourScrollbarUI.class.getName());
```

Comment: At the moment all I have is `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new CustomScrollBarUI());` But once I've created the UI object, I can't see how I can update or modify it after I've created it.

Comment: @paranoid-android You can also try: getVerticalScrollBar().getUI()

Comment: I can reference it fine, but not sure how to update / reinstall.

Comment: After you call UIManger.put(....) try this `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();`